# Activation of WSearch in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012

I want to activate indexing service so that I can start programs by pressing the Windows key and typing the program name. I read that on Windows Server 2016 this is done by issuing this command in PowerShell.

```
Set-Service -Name WSearch -StartupType Automatic -Status Running
```

Unfortunately this does not work in Windows Server 2012 and I cannot find the service in services.msc. Wikipedia says, that the service is available. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows Server 2012 you need to install this service first.

```
Get-WindowsFeature Search-Service | Install-Windowsfeature
```